# Exercise and database for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm a trainer and I need some advanced sql queries and complex logic exercise along with a database. I've used sql-ex.ru site. So anything other than that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TSQL Challenges](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/tc/)

Comment: it'd be great if there are a set of questions from a single database

Comment: @sam there's nothing stopping you from creating your own database using all the creation scripts there...